# Django TestCase objects.create

Tags: django

I'm trying to get a working test for a django demo project i am working on..

The test and model is posted in the following pastebin (SO was showing code error)

http://pastebin.com/B6F23rzJ

The test output i am getting is

[image]

When testing both in the shell and test.py i am seeing TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'

If anyone could help with the create_post function i would really appreciate it..

Comment: -1 for screenshot instead of simply cutting and pasting the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you define your own `save` method for `Post` model?

Then, add `*args`, `**kwargs` to the method parameter.

Also don't forget to call `super(Post, self).save(.., *args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: Thanks yes i had.. 
Changed to super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
And both tests passing..

Comment: @campervancoder, Please update your question. Replace the image with text to make it easy other users to search.

Comment: I have had real challenges with the SO editor advising the code entered is in the wrong format. The only way i could even show the Traceback was to add it as an image..

Comment: @campervancoder, Copy&paste the traceback. Select the traceback. Click code sample button or press Ctrl+K.